# How to deserialize specific json string to ASP.NET MVC model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I have json string like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            ...
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 9283.92,
                    "volume_24h": 7155680000,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.152774,
                    "percent_change_24h": 0.518894,
                    "market_cap": 158055024432,
                    "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
                },
                "BTC": {
                    "price": 1,
                    "volume_24h": 772012,
                    "percent_change_1h": 0,
                    "percent_change_24h": 0,
                    "percent_change_7d": 0,
                    "market_cap": 17024600,
                    "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
                }
            }
        },
        // objects like previous from which i need the data
    ],
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z",
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I deserialize it into models like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public double Percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double Percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public long Market_cap { get; set; }
    public DateTime Last_updated { get; set; }
}
```

The field names in the model are the same as the key names in json string.

I'm new to C# and I couldn't find any helpful information about my question, especially because of this specific json string structure.
I'll be glad if you direct me any good links about this.

Comment: When you have json string and want to convert it to model classes. Then copy that json and go to a class in C# and click on top Edit menu > Paste Special > Paste Json As Classes. It will generate model for your json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model seems to be something like this.

```
public class Model
{
   public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
   public Status status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public Quote quote { get; set; }
}
public class Quote
{
    public USD USD { get; set; }
   public BTC BTC { get; set; }
}
public class BTC
{
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int volume_24h { get; set; }
    public int percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public int percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public int percent_change_7d { get; set; }
    public int market_cap { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
}

public class USD
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public object volume_24h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_1h { get; set; }
    public double percent_change_24h { get; set; }
    public object market_cap { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
}
```

You can also try creating model on (http://json2csharp.com/) by copying your valid json string.
Please let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

- Bottom line: You *can* (manually), but that's probably not what you're looking for.
- Reason: Your model doesn't match the JSON structure, hence "manual"
- You can use readily available tools in either Visual Studio or VS Code to help you with creating the proper model (e.g. [Paste JSON As Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype))
- Once you get the "proper" model/s ready, go over [JSON documentation for (de)serializing](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix some syntax errors on your json, so fixed version is following:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "quote": {
          "USD": {
            "price": 9283.92,
            "volume_24h": 7155680000,
            "percent_change_1h": -0.152774,
            "percent_change_24h": 0.518894,
            "market_cap": 158055024432,
            "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
          },
          "BTC": {
            "price": 1,
            "volume_24h": 772012,
            "percent_change_1h": 0,
            "percent_change_24h": 0,
            "percent_change_7d": 0,
            "market_cap": 17024600,
            "last_updated": "2018-08-09T22:53:32.000Z"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "status": {
        "timestamp": "2018-06-02T22:51:28.209Z"
    }
}
```

Here is C# model classes matching with previous json:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
        public Status status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Status
    {
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public Quote quote { get; set; }
    }

    public class Quote
    {
        public USD USD { get; set; }
        public BTC BTC { get; set; }
    }

    public class USD
    {
        public float price { get; set; }
        public long volume_24h { get; set; }
        public float percent_change_1h { get; set; }
        public float percent_change_24h { get; set; }
        public long market_cap { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
    }

    public class BTC
    {
        public int price { get; set; }
        public int volume_24h { get; set; }
        public int percent_change_1h { get; set; }
        public int percent_change_24h { get; set; }
        public int percent_change_7d { get; set; }
        public int market_cap { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is code snippet which you can use when deserializing your json. This snippet uses [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)-library.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText("object.json"));
```